# Does every finitely presented group have a finite index subgroup with free abelianisation?

Tags: group-theory, covering-spaces, compact-manifolds, free-abelian-group

> Let $G$ be a finitely presented group. Does there exist a finite index subgroup $H$ such that its abelianisation $H^{\text{ab}} = H/[H, H]$ is free abelian?

Note, if $G^{\text{ab}}$ is not already free abelian, then it is non-zero and surjects onto a non-trivial finite group, so $G$ admits a finite index subgroup.

My motivation comes from compact manifolds. If $M$ is a compact manifold, then $\pi_1(M)$ is finitely presented and its abelianisation is $H_1(M; \mathbb{Z})$ which is a finitely generated abelian group which may have torsion. A finite index subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ corresponds to a finite cover $N \to M$. So my question above is asking whether I can take a finite cover $N$ of $M$ such that $H_1(N; \mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free.

If $M = k\mathbb{RP}^2$ is a non-orientable surface, then $H_1(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$. Its orientable double cover $N = \Sigma_{k-1}$ has $H_1(N; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2k-2}$ which is torsion-free. This example shows that the rank of $H_1$ can change by passing to covers (in terms of groups, the rank of the abelianisation can change by passing to finite index subgroups).

If $G$ is virtually free, then of course the answer is yes. Nilpotent groups also have the desired finite index subgroups, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/73649/21564). In this case, more is true. Namely, the finite index subgroup $H$ can be chosen so that $H^{\text{ab}}$ has the same rank as $G^{\text{ab}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Baumslag-Solitar group* $\mathrm{BS}(1,n)$ is the group with presentation $\langle a, t \mid tat^{-1} = a^n \rangle$. It is easy to check that $\mathrm{BS}(1,n)$ has torsion in its Abelianisation when $n > 2$. Moreover, it is known that all the finite index subgroups of $\mathrm{BS}(1,n)$ are isomorphic to $\mathrm{BS}(1,m)$ for some value $m \geqslant n$. It follows that all of the finite index subgroups of $\mathrm{BS}(1,n)$ have torsion in their Abelianisation.

It might be worth mentioning that $\mathrm{BS}(1,n)$ is solvable, so the fact about nilpotent groups that you mentioned in your question does not extend to solvable groups.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the fact that a finite index subgroup of $BS(1, n)$ is isomorphic to $BS(1, m)$ for some $m \geq n$? I did a quick google search and was unsuccessful.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: A fairly simple case is when $n=p$ is prime, so that the normal closure $A=\langle\langle a\rangle\rangle$ of $a$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$. Any finite index subgroup $H$ will intersect this in a finite index subgroup, so that $H\cap A\cong m\mathbb{Z}[1/p]=\langle\langle a^m\rangle\rangle$ for some $m$ coprime to $p$. Since the image of $H$ has finite index in $G/A$, $H$ also contains some $t^ka^r$. These end up generating $H$ and it's not hard to see what the action of $t^ka^r$ does to $a^m$.

Comment: One way to do the general case is with Bass-Serre theory. Realise BS$(1,n)$ as an HNN extension $\mathbb Z*_{\mathbb Z}$ and look at the action on the Bass-Serre tree. It is a directed tree with $n$ incoming edges and one outgoing edge at each vertex. The quotient graph by a finite index subgroup will be finite, and you can show that because the action is orientation preserving it must be a loop representing some BS$(1,n^k)$. @Steve D's comment suffices though, without using Bass-Serre theory.